# django convert fbv to cbv that uses filter and search form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a FBV that have a filter in the template, which I'm processing with POST and a search processed by GET. What is the proper way to convert this code to a CBV?

I'm thinking of using the TemplateView and overriding the get and post methods, but the way I'm thinking would be just to create the class and implementing the methods (there would be lot's of duplicated code).

this is my view:

```
def control_list(request):
    group_status = STATUS_LIST
    group_query_idx = 1
    period_initial = date.today()-timedelta(days=30)
    period_final = date.today()

    if request.method == "POST":
        filter_form = FilterControl(request.POST)
        if filter_form.is_valid():
            group_query_idx = int(filter_form.cleaned_data['group_status'])
            period_initial = filter_form.cleaned_data['period_initial']
            period_final = filter_form.cleaned_data['period_final']

    else:
        filter_form = FilterControl()

    if group_query_idx:
        filtered_groups = Group.objects.filter_by_status(group_status[group_query_idx])

    queryset_list = Control.objects.filter_by_group_status(group_status[group_query_idx])\
        .filter(published__range=[period_initial, period_final])

    controls_per_group = {}
    for group in filtered_groups:
        control = queryset_list.filter(group_id=group.id)
        controls_per_group[group.title] = control

    context = {
        "object_list": queryset_list,
        "title": "Control",
        "controls_per_group": controls_per_group,
        "column": range(10),
        "group_status": group_status,
        "filter_form": filter_form,
    }
```

This is what I did, it works but there is a lot of duplicated code:

```
class ControlList(TemplateView):
    template_name = "control_list.html"

    def get(self, request):
        group_status = STATUS_LIST
        group_query_idx = 1
        period_initial = date.today() - timedelta(days=30)
        period_final = date.today()

        filter_form = FilterControl()
        filtered_groups = Group.objects.filter_by_status(group_status[group_query_idx])

        queryset_list = Control.objects.filter_by_group_status(group_status[group_query_idx]) \
            .filter(published__range=[period_initial, period_final])

        # if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        #     queryset_list = Control.objects.all()

        controls_per_group = {}
        for group in filtered_groups:
            control = queryset_list.filter(group_id=group.id)
            controls_per_group[group.title] = control 

        context = {
            "object_list": queryset_list,
            "title": "Control",
            "controls_per_group": controls_per_group,
            "column": range(10),
            "group_status": group_status,
            "filter_form": filter_form,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request):
        filter_form = FilterControl(request.POST)
        group_status = STATUS_LIST
        group_query_idx = 1
        if filter_form.is_valid():
            group_query_idx = int(filter_form.cleaned_data['group_status'])
            period_initial = filter_form.cleaned_data['period_initial']
            period_final = filter_form.cleaned_data['period_final']
            group_status = group_status[group_query_idx]

        if group_query_idx:
            filtered_groups = Group.objects.filter_by_status(group_status)

        queryset_list = Control.objects.filter_by_group_status(group_status) \
            .filter(published__range=[period_initial, period_final])

        # if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        #     queryset_list = Control.objects.all()

        controls_per_group = {}
        for group in filtered_groups:
            control = queryset_list.filter(group_id=group.id)
            controls_per_group[group.title] = control

        context = {
            "object_list": queryset_list,
            "title": "Control",
            "controls_per_group": controls_per_group,
            "column": range(10),
            "group_status": group_status,
            "filter_form": filter_form,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: please update your indentation...

Comment: indentation updated

Comment: Posted my implementation.